# Sharepoint 2013 Office 365 Master Page Branding Help

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page, page-layout, branding, custom-masterpage

I have been tasked with developing my organizations intranet with Sharepoint 2013. I'd like to be able to brand it so it matches the look of our organization but I keep hitting road blocks so I was hoping to get some answers to some questions I am having trouble with.

So far I have created a html/css page on dreamweaver and I have imported that into sharepoint. **Here is a picture of what that looks like below.** I should add that I am fairly new to sharepoint. But I have read a lot about how to design master pages, I just need some guidance. **Also I am happy to talk offline and provide compensation for anyone who would be willing to give me some advice.**

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBJ1a.jpg][1]

**Question #1,** What happened to my footer? It seems to have disappeared from my design. Here is what the footer is supposed to look like.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aRY9.jpg][2]

What am I missing? I tried putting a container on the around the html code for the whole page at 1414px wide (the size of the footer and the size of the header) but it still won't show. Sometimes i even see the footer flicker at the bottom of the page for a millisecond, but then it goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're starting with SharePoint, then I suggest looking at doing things in the right way. The recommended way of branding SharePoint sites (specially SharePoint Online, but also on premises) is not to use master pages.

You can get away with doing a well-designed website with only CSS and this is what most people who really know SharePoint are doing. At some point, you will have things getting broken in your website because of the edits on the master page.

Here are few articles as a guidance on why you shouldn't be editing the master page, and I suggest you read articles by Heather Solomon, you'll find a lot of information on how to brand SharePoint with only CSS.

Branding SPO: 
http://www.degdigital.com/insights/dos-and-donts-for-creating-custom-sharepoint-online-designs/

Advices on Microsoft O365 Branding: 
http://www.microsofttrends.com/2015/05/07/latest-advice-on-office-365-branding/

Example how to style SPO with only CSS by Heather Solomon:

http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2016/02/sptechcon-2016-css-session-recap/

Comment: Thanks Mohammed, any idea on why the footer is now missing from the page?

Comment: Without looking at the html, it would be hard to tell what's going on. Can you post your html somewhere?

Comment: add the html for the footer as an edit to this question, and if u can add all the html to pastebin, and put the link here